# Create user - map network drive CMD

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, remote-access, mapped-drive

I have a pipeline which I want to do automatically (probably with a bat file) without the need to do all steps manually on my windows 10 machine.

Pipeline steps:

1. Create a normal user account e.g userA. I know this can be done using this `net user userA passuserA /add`
2. Map network drive using cmd, I know this can be done using `net use * \\myshared\directory /u:domainname\domuserA password` but I wonder if this will work without being logged in the machine? which brings me to my question is there a way Login to the computer using userA remotely once it's created then mount the drive to the user. My goal is that to put all this in a batch file and run it so that I don't have to repeat these steps but I am not sure how it can be done?

Comment: You normally map drives with log on scripts.

Comment: @Mark can you show me how?

Comment: Ask at https://serverfault.com the sister web site for these types of questions.